# Find an item by type in a dynamic hierarchy

Tags: c#, .net, linq

A colleague of mine asked an interesting Question. Imagine the following object structure

Project --> Sprints --> Stories --> Tasks

My colleague is just interested in the tasks. Nothing else. Every task has its own id and he wants to select all tasks of a project **WITHOUT** knowing the exact hierarchy of the type **Project**. When somebody changes something in the hierarchy (adds or deletes a level) he has now also to fix the query to get all the tasks.

Is there a good way to achieve this? Maybe something like this:

```
IEnumerable<Project> projects = GetProjectBy(...);
IEnumerable<Task> = projects.ItemsOfTypeInHierarchy<Task>();
```

Is it possible without reflection?

(I know how it works with  `.SelectMany` and knowing the exact structure)

Comment: Is adding or removing a level really a common thing to worry about? That's a pretty significant data model change...

Comment: Of course, in the most scenarios it would be a significant change. But the given scenario is just an example. I think there could be situations where you want to have an item in a hierarchy without knowing the hierarchy itself.

Comment: And at that point, reflection is a pretty natural thing to use. Basically, if it's all dynamic or effectively dynamic, use reflection. Otherwise, use your knowledge of the model...

Comment: why is it a requirement to achieve this without reflection?

Comment: @Dominik, it's not a requirement! Its just a question if it is possible somehow without reflection (with any kind of pattern or so)

Answer (score 0):

Does each part of the model expose its children through some common interface or base class? If they implement something in common as simple as

```
public interface IHierarchicalParent
{
    IEnumerable<IHierarchicalParent> Children { get; }
}
```

you can search the tree recursively without reflection.

If you can't modify each class, you could write an adapter for each type--although then you have to write a bunch of wrappers. Flexibly choosing which wrapper to make involves some type-checking depending on your use case (`is`, `as`, clever use of `dynamic`, or something) but no reflecting into the members.

You could also "flatten" your adapters into a single method that takes the base entity object and returns an enumerable of the same type.

However, if you can determine a specific hierarchy at compilation, you can avoid reflecting on the type at all. You can do this by making the `ProjectAdapter` return an enumerable of `SprintAdapter`s as its `Children`, for each `Sprint` in its `Project`. This of course makes it inflexible, but there's no type checking at all! Afterwards, just treat all the objects as `IHierarchicalParent` and do the recursive check the same way.

(Moved this answer from my comment and expanded on it.)

Answer (score 0):

This answer is inspired by Miguel Castro (a pluralsight author), and it does use reflection, but I've used it and it performs nicely. Figured, I'd share it due its versatility. You can do much more than just get the objects, you can do whatever you want with them!

Create something akin to an ObjectBase and any class that would need to found in the hierarchy have inherit from that base class. I'm literally copying this out of my source control and tweaking a bit for this post, but the goal of this ObjectBase is to get all the "dirty" objects in the tree by "Walking" the tree. You could pass whatever anonymous method in that you'd like, that anonymous method is what you actually want to that object (add it to a collection,  execute a method, change a property, etc)

```
public abstract class ObjectBase
    {
        //The IsDirty Property
        protected bool _isDirty;
        public bool IsDirty
        {
            get { return _isDirty; }
            set { _isDirty = value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Using this item as the root, walk the tree to get all dirty objects
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>IEnumerable<ObjectBase></returns>
        public IEnumerable<ObjectBase> GetDirtyObjects()
        {
            var dirtyObjects = new List<ObjectBase>();
            WalkTree(
            o =>
            {
                if (o.IsDirty)
                    dirtyObjects.Add(o);

                return false; // can return true to stop walk on first object
            });

            return dirtyObjects;
        }

        ///Sets all DirtyObjects in the tree to clean
        public void CleanTree()
        {
            WalkTree(
            o =>
            {
                o.IsDirty = false;
                return false; // can return true to stop walk on first object
            });

        }

        //Accepts a function to be executed, and any properties that you might want to be excluded
        //in this instance the function we'll be using is getting the dirty objects(above)
        public void WalkTree(Func<ObjectBase, bool> walkSnippet, IEnumerable<string> exemptProperties = null)
        {
            //Create a list of visited objects to prevent looking at the same objects twice
            List<ObjectBase> visited = new List<ObjectBase>();

            //Take into consideration any exemptions via property name
            List<string> exemptions = new List<string>();
            if (exemptProperties != null)
                exemptions = exemptProperties.ToList();

            Walk(this, visited, walkSnippet, exemptions);
        }

        //Does the actual walking of the tree, looking through all the properties
        //on the class, checking to see if that property is of the type, or an 
        //IEnumerable of ObjectBase
        private void Walk(ObjectBase obj, List<ObjectBase> visited, Func<ObjectBase, bool> walkSnippet, IEnumerable<string> exemptions)
        {
            //if you have already checked this object, check it
            if (obj != null && !visited.Contains(obj))
            {
                //add to the visited list
                visited.Add(obj);
                //invoke the walk snippet declared in GetDirtyObjects
                walkSnippet.Invoke(obj);

                //Loop through all the properties that implement ObjectBase
                //or are an IEnumerable<ObjectBase>, that aren't exempt
                foreach (var property in ReflectionHelper.GetTreeProperties(obj, true).Where(x => !exemptions.Contains(x.Name)))
                {
                    //If it's a single object, recurse this method
                    if (property.PropertyType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ObjectBase)))
                    {
                        Walk((ObjectBase)property.GetValue(obj), visited, walkSnippet, exemptions);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //if it's an IEnumerable property, recurse this method
                        //over the collection
                        var objEnumerable = (IEnumerable<ObjectBase>)property.GetValue(obj);
                        if (objEnumerable != null)
                        {
                            foreach (var nestedObj in objEnumerable)
                            {
                                Walk((ObjectBase)nestedObj, visited, walkSnippet, exemptions);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the ReflectionHelper:

```
public static class ReflectionHelper
{
    public static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetTreeProperties<T>(T obj)
    {
        var type = obj.GetType();
        var properties = type.GetProperties()
           .Where(x => x.PropertyType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(T)) || x.GetValue(obj) as IEnumerable<T> != null);

        return properties;
    }
}
```